# Urllb2 package missing from Pypi

Tags: python, web-crawler, urllib2

I wanted to install urllib2 package from PyPI but it is not available.

It seems that it has been updated to urllib3, but is there any way to download urllib2 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib2
```

Is that what you want?

If you find any library under http://docs.python.org/ you can always import without installing it.

Update 1:

If you need the source code...

The official Cpython code: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3b5fdb5bc597/Lib/urllib

> Note The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in
>   Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will
>   automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

or try this?  http://code.reddit.com/docs/urllib2-pysrc.html

I can't guarantee the integrity for the second alternative link.